# Setting up Environment Variables in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, web-config

I have a WCF application which has the 2 default configurations, Debug and Release. I've also added two publishing profiles, Test and Live. throughout my code I make use of a class which has a constructor like so:

```
public MyClass(string server)
{
    server = server.ToLower();
    switch (server)
    {
        case "live":
            LogonToLive();
            break;
        case "test":
            LogonToTest();
            break;
}
```

I then use which throughout my application like so:

```
using(var ax = new MyClass("test"))
{
    // do stuff in my Test Environment
}
```

What I'd like to do is set up some variables in my web.config which will automatically replace `MyClass("test")` with the correct server based on which configuration/publish profile I have set. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the trace constants of [conditional compiling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691099%28VS.71%29.aspx) to determine the build configuration, and pull the desired value from a property in a 'Configuration' class, or something:

```
public static string Server {
  get {
#if DEBUG
    return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key0];
#else
    return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key1];
#endif
  }
}
```

I think determining the publishing profile is a different kettle of fish, so to speak.

Comment: Hi, yeah that works! Just need a way of making it load a configuration based on the publishing profile now

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add one app setting for server name and read it at runt time to find out the server.